# Bug de animação no Firefox

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, css-animations

Eu criei um svg e fiz uma animaçãozinha de carregamento, no estilo de um loader simples... Essa animação funciona perfeitamente no Chrome, mas no Firefox e no Edge contém alguns problemas na animação. No Edge a animação fica congelada, e no Firefox é como se ela não respeitasse as regras de giro, e fica toda louca na tela.

Código css

```
#Layer_1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 125px;
    left: 95%;
}
.loader {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 420px;
}

.plane {
    animation: spin 3000ms linear infinite;
    fill: #FFF;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@keyframes spin{
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Código HTML do SVG:

```
<div id="loading" class="loader" style="display: block">
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 1920 260">
      <g class="plane">
           <path #caminho transform="translate(-871 -451.2)" style="fill: #1e73be"/>
           <path #caminho transform="translate(-871 -451.2)" style="fill: #1e73be"/>
           <path #caminho transform="translate(-871 -451.2)" style="fill: #1e73be"/>
           <path #caminho transform="translate(-871 -451.2)" style="fill: #1e73be"/>
           <path #caminho transform="translate(-871 -451.2)" style="fill: #1e73be"/>
      </g>
 </svg>
```

Será que desse jeito não oferece suporte para outros navegadores além do Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otavio,a Rule @Keyframes não da suporte para a maioria dos navegadores antigos, para você ter ideia, nem tem suporte para o IE, apenas para o Edge 10, ou seja, os navegadores antigos não terão mesmo suporte para as animações. Já o transform, o mesmo dá um suporte mais amplo para os navegadores, mas ainda assim é bastante limitado a alguns navegadores antigos.

Acesse esse [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) para saber a lista completa dos navegadores/versões que suportam a Rule @Keyframe.

Para saber quais navegadores dão suporte ao transform [clique aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

Nesse [site](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Detecting_CSS_animation_support) há alguns exemplos de como detectar se o browser é antigo e realizar a animação de acordo com o suporte que ele fornece,vale a pena dar uma olhada.